# C# Given a custom class and custom attribute how can you find the attributes of a class from the base class

Tags: c#, reflection

Given the following class

```
[KeyField("dap_name")]
public class nhs_acquisition_profile
    : DALObject
    , IDisposable
{
    public nhs_acquisition_profile()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public nhs_acquisition_profile(String ConnectionString)
        : base(ConnectionString)
    {

    }


}
```

How could I find the value of the KeyField Attribute but from the base class.

Comment: `this.GetType()` is probably your friend, if I understand your scenario correctly. If not, it could do with some sample code to better illustrate your problem.

Comment: You can use relection on the DALObject type to find its inheritors and then get the custom attributes on those - but you'll still need to know which one you're looking for, though - so that might not be what you're after if for some reason you need to do this via the base type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you need it in a construction phase

```
public DALObject() // base constructor
{
    var fieldAttr = GetType() // real type
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyFieldAttribute), true) // look for attribute
        .FirstOrDefault(); // can take more than one, it's an example
    var resultField = (fieldAttr as KeyFieldAttribute)?.Field; // cast and use
}
```

The same code will works the same in other functions in the class